# How to alter a variable via a dictionary?

Tags: python

How would you go about changing a variables value using a dictionary?

```
class Solution(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.slot1 = ""
    self.slot2 = ""
    self.slot3 = ""
    self.slot4 = ""
    self.slot5 = ""
    self.slotDictionary = {1: self.slot1, 2: self.slot2, 3: self.slot3, 4: self.slot4, 5: self.slot5}
  def checkAnswer(self):
    choice = int(input("What is the answer?"))
    self.slotDictionary[choice] = "something"
solution = Solution()
solution.checkAnswer()
```

However when running this it does not change the value of the self variables. How would i go about this?

Comment: Just drop the different slotX variables and ***only*** have the dictionary or even replace it with a list.

Comment: Your initialization of `self.slotDictionary` is *exactly* equivalent to `{1: "", 2: "", 3: "", 4: "", 5: ""}`.  Nothing is storing the fact that all those empty strings came from particular attributes; in fact, they're almost certainly all the very same string object.

Comment: Dictionaries *contain objects*. They do not contain variables (like any other container).

Comment: Trying to keep the same information in two places can be difficult. Is there any reason why you need the 'slotX' variables?

Answer (score -1):

You can't change an immutable object (like str). You have initialized your attribute with an immutable object so, python will always create a new object in order to modify the value (the reference will be different between the one store in the attribut and the one store in your dictionary after modifying your attribute).
If you use a mutable type, like list, dict or a specific class, you will be able, in this case, to modify the object you want.

Note: there is many other approach to deal with your problem. Passing your attribut through other attribut of the class is not a common use case and maybe a wrong materialization of the problem. If your purpose is to make a choice on your attributs list "self.**dict**" with "getattr" may help you.

Comment: There is some inaccuracies in the way this is stated. **Variables** are neither mutable or immutable -- objects are. This: "You have initialize your variables with a non mutable, unreferenced variable so, python will always copy it in order to modify it" is also very confusing. You need to take care to use the terminology like "variable" correctly. It is mroe straightforwad to say simply that "immutable objects **cannot be modified**, instead, new objects can be created from their methods". Not "python will copy them in order to modify them", since "immutable" means "unmodifiable"

Comment: I agree the fact that variable are not object (I will change the terminology)

Comment: ```setattr``` is what this person needs.  They want to change the variable by its literal string name.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is logically not possible but there is hack you may use. And it's by using `list`. If you wrap `str` with a `list` then it can be achieved.

Check the code below:

```
class Solution(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.slot1 = [""]
    self.slot2 = [""]
    self.slot3 = [""]
    self.slot4 = [""]
    self.slot5 = [""]
    self.slotDictionary = {1: self.slot1, 2: self.slot2, 3: self.slot3, 4: self.slot4, 5: self.slot5}
  def checkAnswer(self):
    choice = int(input("What is the answer?"))
    self.slotDictionary[choice][0] = "something"
solution = Solution()
solution.checkAnswer()
```

Comment: If you are going to do this, don't use a `list`, jsut create a custom class, e.g. `class Value:` that simply has an attribute `value` that you modify

Comment: @alvrm it seems you didn't understand the problem. you can't use `setattr`  to change both objects in a dict and class value at once. `setattr` is used to set a value to the object's attribute. He is already can do this without using `setattr` by simply using `solution.slot1 = "value"`.

Comment: @rafathasan That's not at all what was asked... ```How would you go about changing a variable's value using a dictionary?```  settatr() is exactly what's needed.

Comment: @alvrm if you look closely to MG's code he is putting immutable class value into  a `dict` and he want to change the class value by changing the dict objects.

Answer (score -2):

You can change class variables by their string (name) with `setattr()`.

```
class Solution(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.slot1 = ""
    self.slot2 = ""
    self.slot3 = ""
    self.slot4 = ""
    self.slot5 = ""
    self.slotDictionary = {1: 'slot1', 2: 'slot2', 3: 'slot3', 4: 'slot4', 5: 'slot5'}
  def checkAnswer(self):
    choice = int(input("What is the answer?"))
    setattr(self, self.slotDictionary[choice], "something")
solution = Solution()
solution.checkAnswer()
```

And to get the variable using the dictionary do this:

`value = getattr(self, self.slotDictionary[choice])`